# HTTP interface to industrial motion controller using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, http

I am using Excel VBA to communicate with an Industrial Motion Controller using HTTP protocol.
Here is what I am doing & it is working well.

---

```
  ColumnCountA = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   a3 = 1

   For a1 = 0 To ColumnCountA - 1


        Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        URL = "http://127.0.0.1/kas//plcvariables"
        objHTTP.Open "PUT", URL, False


        a2 = CStr(a1)
        a4 = CStr(a3)

        strDATA1Array = "Sample1Array[" + a2 + "]=" + LTrim((Application.ActiveSheet.Range("a" + a4).Value))
        strDATA2Array = "Sample2Array[" + a2 + "]=" + LTrim(Str(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("b" + a4).Value))


        strSendToKAS = strDATA1Array + "," + strDATA2Array + ","


        objHTTP.send (strSendToKAS)


        a3 = a3 + 1

   Next
```

---

With above code, I am able to send all contents of Column A & B to the motion controller in form of arrays (strData1Array, strData2Array).

I have below questions-
1. I want the user to know that this data transfer is completed (the cell count can typically go to 5000. So it takes 8-10 seconds to complete the actual data transfer). Do we get any 'data transfer done' acknowledgement bit at excel side?
2. I plan to use a button "Clear data in Motion controller". After pressing this button, I want all previously sent HTTP data to be reseted to 0. How to do that? I tried pushing 0 in A & B columns but my excel program hangs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things: 
You're code is creating a new object for `objHTTP` in every loop.  This seems like a potential waste of resources.  I would move this statement outside the loop.  Also, next line doesn't use any variables from your loop so there seems to be no point in having it inside the loop either.

The `Open` line does need to be in the loop, as per the documentation for [IServerXMLHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754586(v=vs.85).aspx) the `Send` method requires both an `Open` and `Send` each time.  Being the case, I would move them closer together so it is more obvious what you are doing.

As for checking if the command has completed, you can check the [ReadyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761388(v=vs.85).aspx) property.

I'm not *entirely* sure I grasped what you mean about deleting the previous HTTP commands, but I think you're saying you want to erase them from the excel workbook.  You can use [ClearContents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff835589.aspx) to do that.

```
  ColumnCountA = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   a3 = 1
   Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   URL = "http://127.0.0.1/kas//plcvariables"


   For a1 = 0 To ColumnCountA - 1   

        a2 = CStr(a1)
        a4 = CStr(a3)

        strDATA1Array = "Sample1Array[" + a2 + "]=" + LTrim((Application.ActiveSheet.Range("a" + a4).Value))
        strDATA2Array = "Sample2Array[" + a2 + "]=" + LTrim(Str(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("b" + a4).Value))


        strSendToKAS = strDATA1Array + "," + strDATA2Array + ","

        objHTTP.Open "PUT", URL, False    
        objHTTP.send (strSendToKAS)

        'Check if the data transfer is complete
        Do While objHTTP.ReadyState <> 4
             Do Events
        Loop    

        'Do something to inform the user the data transfer has completed  
        MsgBox("The HTTP data transfer has completed")

        a3 = a3 + 1

   Next

   ColumnCountA.ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks. The ReadyState property helped me.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd question- I am already clearing all contents in excel when I want to transfer a new data to my controller every time. But for example, if I have already sent array of 100 strings to the controller & now I want to send only 50 strings, then other 50 bytes in my controller don't become 0. so i want to give a button in Excel saying " clear controller data". When i press that button, I want to send 0 to all the strings (total 3000 in both column A & B). I tried sending data similar to the way I am sending but the excel hangs.

Comment: I'm still not following what you mean by "send 0 to all the strings".  Are you saying you want to make all the cells in columns a and b of excel "0"? Or are you saying you need to send an array containing 100 strings, each consisting of "0", to your controller?

Comment: Hi. My problem is solved now. I was making some small mistakes in coding.Thanks a lot for your earlier inputs.